# Trigger build pipeline (on the same branch) on completion of another pipeline

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, azure-devops-server-2019

In our Azure DevOps Server 2019 we want to trigger a build pipeline on completion of another build pipeline. The triggered build should use the same source branch the triggering build used.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops-2019&tabs=yaml) this does not work with classic builds or the classic trigger definition, but in the YAML definition for the triggered build:

build.yaml:

```
# define triggering build as resource
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: ResourceName
      source: TriggeringBuildPipelineName
      trigger:
        branches:
          - '*'

# another ci build trigger
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - '*'
  paths:
    include:
      - SubFoldder

pool:
  name: Default
```

When creating the pipeline like this, the `trigger` element under the `pipeline` resource gets underlined and the editor states that `trigger` is **not** expected inside a `pipeline`.

When saving the definition and trying to run it, it fails with this error:

> /SubFolder/build.yaml (Line: 6, Col: 7): Unexpected value 'trigger'

(where "line 6" is the `trigger` line in the `resources` definition).

So my **question** is: How to correctly declare a trigger that starts a build pipeline on completion of another build pipeline, using the same source branch? Since the linked documentation actually explains this, the question rather is: what did I miss, why is `trigger` unexpected at this point?

---

Update: I just found [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/954120/pipeline-trigger-unexpected-value-trigger.html). So it seems one of the main features that they promised to have and documented as working, one of the main features we switched to DevOps for, is not even implemented, yet. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updates are made every few weeks to the cloud-hosted version, Azure DevOps Services. These updates are then rolled up and made available through quarterly updates to the on-premises Azure DevOps Server and TFS.So, all features are release in Azure DevOps Service first.

A timeline of feature released and those planned in the feature release can be found at here-- **[Azure DevOps Feature Timeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/features-timeline)**

You could choose to directly use cloud version Azure DevOps Service instead or monitor latest update on above Feature Timeline with Azure DevOps Server. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately I can't find any related feature in the timeline, so it seems this functionality will not be availabe in reasonable time. So we'll go back to use [this trigger-build-task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks) from the market place.